# Can resizing a partition give chkdsk more clusters for recovery?

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

`chkdsk /f /r` is showing "The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters". I know I need to replace the drive, but some files were not readable when I went to copy the data off.  Would resizing the partition to leave some unallocated space on the drive allow chkdsk to use this unallocated space for recovery so I can finish getting the data off the drive?

Comment: Writing anything at all to the drive would significantly reduce your chances of success. Any data in bad clusters was either already re-mapped during normal operation or contains no usable data, it's gone. Concentrate on the recovery aspect if you failed to keep your backup up to date.

Comment: If you are running Windows 10 with enough memory, you could try turning off the pagefile and hibernation. It might also help to delete the USN Journal __fsutil usn deletejournal /n c:__ the journal alone can be a couple of gigabytes. After the computer reboots turn back on the pagefile, and if it is a laptop also turn back on hibernation.

Comment: I know any writes carry risk.  I'm thinking of trying this after I've already gotten everything I can off.  I just wasn't sure if the sectors used by chkdsk are only the sectors set aside by the drive manufacturer, or if any unallocated sectors could be used.

Comment: @vssher - I am sincerely hoping none of this is being done on a 'live' system. That would be madness. The drive should already be isolated to prevent writes. Keegan, you should be thinking of `dd` now, to work on a copy, not trying to 'fix' broken sectors. Those sectors already contain no useful data. Fixing broken sectors is for when the drive still has useful reallocation resources. By the time it doesn't you're almost too late.

Comment: Everytime you run the system it is writting to the disk(s)

Comment: @vssher - which is precisely why the drive should have already been isolated & why running it 'live' is madness.

Comment: @Tetsujin I do agree totally, however, there really isn't much information about which drive he is trying to fix, also, he could put the disk into another PC, perhaps.

Comment: It's not the Windows OS drive, it's a JBOD data drive. I booted into Linux, mounted the drive read-only and copied files off.  I was now looking for options for the 1/2 dozen files that had IO errors.  I tried ddrescue on a couple of the files, but it also got an IO error, which is why I was looking again at chkdsk.

Comment: Also frustrating (though I know it's been know to happen), there were no SMART errors (still aren't, when viewed with GSmartControl), the only reason I noticed as a disk performance degradation, which I originally thought was caused by Windows April updates. I'm surprised chkdsk and running the Western Digital scan didn't cause SMART errors to show up, even though they weren't there originally.

Comment: The drive was always an internal, not over USB?

Comment: Yes, internal. I know USB often doesn't show SMART, depending on the hardware used.

Comment: I guess then that you got an unfortunate catastrophic failure. They happen, nothing anyone can do to avoid them. Bin it & go to your backup. The lost sectors are lost, that's it; gone. Reallocation now is 'closing the stable door after the horse has bolted'. Don't waste your time with it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to write anything on damaged HDD (bad sectors), it will make more problems. You can try to use some software like UFS explorer and try to read some more data from damaged HDD. They have additional options compared to classic copy.